# HTSQL - Get Count/number of records to be returned by a query

Tags: django, datatables, htsql

I am trying to achieve server side pagination with [HTSQL](http://htsql.org/) and [jQuery Datatables](https://datatables.net/) with server side being Django. The datatable initially requires total number of records so that it could manage the pagination. So if I have a simple HTSQL query like:

```
/program
```

(click the link below for preview)

[/program](http://demo.htsql.org/program)

I would simply do:

```
/count(program)
```

[/count(program)](http://demo.htsql.org/count%28program%29)

and I would get the total number of records which my simple query is going to return. But for instance, if I have a HTSQL query like:

```
/program.filter(school_code=$code){school_code, code, title}:where($code:='eng')
```

[/program.filter(school_code=$code){school_code, code, title}:where($code:='eng')](http://demo.htsql.org/program.filter%28school_code=%24code%29%7Bschool_code,%20code,%20title%7D%3awhere%28%24code%3a=%27eng%27%29)

(my Queries are much more complex than that but this would do for an example. Like I have distinct '^' as well as nested queries)

and now I want to get a count of number of records I would get if I run this query so that I could further use it to initialize any table for server side pagination. I tried:

```
/count(program.filter(school_code=$code){school_code, code, title}:where($code:='eng'))
```

[/count(program.filter(school_code=$code){school_code, code, title}:where($code:='eng'))](http://demo.htsql.org/count%28program.filter%28school_code=%24code%29%7Bschool_code,%20code,%20title%7D%3awhere%28%24code%3a=%27eng%27%29%29)

but got error "Function 'count' expects 1 argument; got 3".

Any clue how could I get the count/number of records which my query is going to return?

Comment: Ff you remove the selector {} it should count the records for you; we'll think about this some, perhaps this should work by disregarding the selector.  DataTables is kinda cool, it'd be slick to see that working -:)

Comment: Yea, clarkevans, when I removed the selectors it gives me the count. But, as I have nested queries(and big ones), I will have to play with regex and do a lot of string manipulations to remove the selectors to get the count at runtime. Anyways, thanks for the help:) You may write it as an answer so that I could mark it as a right answer.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the selector {}  from `count()` and the records count will correct.

```
/count(program.filter(school_code=$code):where($code:='eng'))
```